# valores nulos en mssql al crear foreign key

Tags: sql-server, mssql

Creo dos tablas de en sql server de la siguiente manera:

```
create table personas
(
    id int PRIMARY KEY not null identity,
    nombre_persona varchar(24)
)

create table coches
(
    nombre_persona int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES personas(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    vehiculo varchar(24)
)
```

inserto datos:

```
insert into personas (nombre_persona) values ('juan')
insert into personas (nombre_persona) values ('jose')
insert into personas (nombre_persona) values ('aniceto')
insert into personas (nombre_persona) values ('raul')


insert into coches (vehiculo) values ('mercedes')
insert into coches (vehiculo) values ('seat')
insert into coches (vehiculo) values ('ferrari')
insert into coches (vehiculo) values ('porche')
```

pero al hacer la consulta de la tabla coche me salen los valores en null , me deberia poner la persona a la que pertenece cada coche no como ago para que me aparezca ?

```
select * from coches

nombre_persona    vehiculo
  NULL            mercedes
  NULL            seat
  NULL            ferrari
  NULL            porche
```

Comment: La consulta actual máximo mostrará la fk que sirve como vínculo entre ambas tablas, ¿ya probaste hacer un join?, además en coches te falta insertar la FK asociada

Comment: con un join me salen a null tambien, te refieres en el insert ?

Comment: ¿cómo puede saber el motor que  `juan`  tienen un `mercedes`?

Comment: ¿`mysql` o `sql-server`?

Comment: sql-server......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El código que muestras indica que no estás insertando valores en la columna nombre_persona de la tabla coche. No hay nada que los relacione para que automáticamente aparezca un valor. Por otro lado, no deberías hacer la relación entre tablas mediante el nombre sino mediante las llaves primarias.

El código tendría que ser algo así

```
create table persona
(
    id int PRIMARY KEY not null identity,
    nombre_persona varchar(24)
)

create table coche
(
    id_persona int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES persona(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    vehiculo VARCHAR(24)
)


insert into persona (nombre_persona) values ('juan')
insert into persona (nombre_persona) values ('jose')
insert into persona (nombre_persona) values ('aniceto')
insert into persona (nombre_persona) values ('raul')


insert into coche (id_persona, vehiculo) 
SELECT id, 'mercedes' FROM persona WHERE nombre_persona = 'juan'
UNION ALL
SELECT id, 'seat' FROM persona WHERE nombre_persona = 'jose'
UNION ALL
SELECT id, 'ferrari' FROM persona WHERE nombre_persona = 'aniceto'
UNION ALL
SELECT id, 'porche' FROM persona WHERE nombre_persona = 'raul'
UNION ALL
SELECT id, 'ford' FROM persona WHERE nombre_persona = 'raul'

SELECT *
FROM persona p
JOIN coche   c ON p.id = c.id_persona;
```

Si te fijas, no se necesita que haya una relación directa de uno a uno entre las tablas. Puede haber personas con más de un coche, o podría haber personas sin coche.

Comment: Debe de haber una manera mas simple de hacerlo en mysql si me aparece la clave foranea

Comment: deberia de replicarese la clave foranea sin decirle nada en que sea que ponga una aleatoria

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres un valor aleatorio? Imagina que fuera una tabla de pagos y se aplicaran a personas de forma aleatoria. Sería todo un caos y nadie recibiría el pago que le corresponde.

Comment: en lugar de cohes se podria poner colores a cada persona le corresponde un color aleatorio como se haria ??? y por que me siguen saliendo valores nulos ?quiero enteneder eso

Comment: Porque no es la responsabilidad de la base de datos asignar valores aleatorios. Para eso se necesita un código adicional que asigne los valores aleatorios. La base de datos debe almacenar únicamente lo que se le pida que se almacene y no cambiar los datos.

Comment: @ortiga ahí estás mezclando lógica de negocio (necesitar un valor aleatorio en alguna parte) con el código que guarda, lee, actualiza o borra datos. Mala idea.

Comment: es solo una bd de ejemplo para practicar los join, no voy hacer ninguna empresa solo quiero aprender si alguien me dice algun ejemplo seria util